# Looking for applications of a nice result in linear algebra

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, linear-algebra

Hello everybody

There is a nice classical result in linear algebra: if $A, B$ are two matrices in $M_n(k),$ where $k$ is a field, and $B$ commutes with every element of $M_n(k)$ which commutes with $A$, then $B = f(A)$ for some polynomial $f(x)$ in $k[x].$

I was wondering if anybody knows any (important) theorem which is proved using this result. Thank you.

Comment: You are writing a field as k and as F. 

Comment: This kind of idea occurs in noncommutative algebra under the label "double centralizer theorem".  For instance, you can find some applications in Lam's book on noncommutative rings. 

Comment: But... is this assertion always true? Suppose your field k is the complex number field $\mathbb{C}$. Doesn't exp(A) commute with all the matrices with which A commutes? 


Comment: That means, that $exp(A)$ can be written a polynomial in $A$. The point is that this polynomial may (and will) depend on $A$ itself.

Comment: @unkown(google). Despite its appearance, exp(A) *is* a polynomial on A. That is, for every A, you can find a polynomial r(t) such that exp(A)= r(A). It is the Lagrange-Sylvester interpolation polynomial: see the book of Gantmacher, The theory of matrices, http://books.google.es/books?id=ZQ4VPOG4St8C&pg=PA103&lpg=PA103&dq=%22lagrange+-+sylvester+polynomial%22&source=bl&ots=-TcPXtTNZz&sig=XXfsmXzYxAvECsmgjmAl4D1l_ig&hl=ca&ei=aPl3TOOcIqqJ4gaIjo2DBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22lagrange%20-%20sylvester%20polynomial%22&f=false .

Comment: The double centralizer theorem has a lot of uses in representation theory (e. g. the Schur-Weyl duality, which is considered in any reasonable textbook) and in the theory of Azumaya algebras a. k. a. central simple algebras (cf. Milne's Class Field Theory http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/cft.html Chapter 4, or Gille/Szamuely "Central Simple Algebras and Galois Cohomology"). I am still rather mystified about what this theorem actually means and what is the idea behind its proof, but there is no doubt that it uses are many.

Comment: Just to make it a little clearer, the reason that $exp(A)$ is a polynomial in $A$ is that $A$ satisfies its own minimal polynomial, so all terms of degree at least that of the minimal polynomial can be expressed as terms of lower degree, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tate's famous "Endomorphisms of Abelian Varieties over Finite Fields," which proves the Tate conjecture in the finite field case, uses the full force of the theorem of bicommutation in a reduction lemma. As KConrad mentions in the comments, the result you've cited is the special case of this theorem where one works with the subalgebra generated by one element.

Comment: Nice! I had no idea, thanks. That's the paper Tate published in 1966. I think that's kind of applications I'm looking for. Thank you again.

Comment: +1 for "Tate´s famous..." ;)

Answer (score 2):

That result sits inside a wider set of results. Search for spectral theorem, functional calculus of linear operators.

Books could be 
 Halmos, A Hilbert Space problem book
 if you also need to read more about linear operators in general I think in 
 Conway's Functional Analysis there is also stuff about these results, together with an introduction to functional analysis.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know that much about functional analysis but I appreciate your comment very much. Thank you.

Comment: It is interesting to see an answer from the point of functional analysis after an answer involving abelian varieties over *finite* fields!

Answer (score 1):

This probably doesn't qualify as "important", but you put that in parentheses so I'll mention it anyway.

I used that result when figuring out some basic facts about polynomial loops in a compact, connected Lie group which I needed for my paper [the co-Riemannian structure of smooth loop spaces](http://www.math.ntnu.no/~stacey/Research/Preprints/coriemloop.html).